# Arbitrariness of an arbitrary function after an operation

Tags: functions

Let’s say there is an arbitrary function f(x). Now I define another function g(x) = O(f(x)), where O is a mathematical operation (addition, inverse, derivative...whatever). My question is, can g(x) still be regarded as an “arbitrary function”?

My first thought is a no, because g(x) has to satisfy the mathematical operation as stated (i.e. it has to meet certain conditions/restrictions). But later I remember seeing statements such as “an arbitrary REAL number” (i.e. “the number has to be real” is a condition to be met), and now I’m confused.

Comment: $g$ may not be completely arbitrary anymore. For example, if the "O" is the squaring operation, so $g(x) = f(x)^2$, then $g(x)$ is now always non-negative (assuming $f$ is real-valued).

Comment: Thanks for the answers first. So does it mean that a function can still be regarded as “arbitrary” even if there are restrictions on it? Somehow this looks contradictory to me....

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by Minus One-Twelfth, the range of $g$ must be contained in the range of $O$.  But that is the only restriction.  That is, for any function $h$ on some domain $A$ whose 
range is contained in the range of $O$, there is a function $f$ from $A$ into the domain of $O$ such that $h(x) = O(f(x))$ for all $x \in A$.  Namely, for each $x \in A$ we let $f(x)$ be some $y$ such that $O(y) = h(x)$.